# performSelector NSThread issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsthread

Is it possible to cancel a thread while performSelector waitsUntilDone?

See below:

I have a while loop with following line:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(getMyRecords:) onThread:myThread withObject:i waitUntilDone:YES]
```

Sometimes, I need to cancel my thread `myThread` while my loop executes. I get following crash issue:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSDestinationInvalidException', reason: '*** -[MyController performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:]: target thread exited while waiting for the perform'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out the documentation of NSObject:

> This method queues the message on the
>   run loop of the target thread using
>   the default run loop modes—that is,
>   the modes associated with the
>   NSRunLoopCommonModes constant. As part
>   of its normal run loop processing, the
>   target thread dequeues the message
>   (assuming it is running in one of the
>   default run loop modes) and invokes
>   the desired method.
>
> **You cannot cancel messages queued
>   using this method.** If you want the
>   option of canceling a message on the
>   current thread, you must use either
>   the
>   performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:
>   or
>   performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes:
>   method.
>
> This method retains the receiver and
>   the arg parameter until after the
>   selector is performed.

Comment: This answer is in no way related to the question

Comment: It answers the question. Says you can’t cancel

Comment: The question was about cancelling a *thread*, not the message being posted. You suggest using another method of queuing messages so that it fixed the crash of stopping a thread. This is a very misleading answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a long running operation inside a thread, you can declare a condition variable (atomic) like 'canceled' and check it.
something like:

```
- (void) threadFunc {
 while (!canceled){
   // do stuff
 }
}


- (void) cancelThread {
 canceled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use `NSThread's` [-(void)cancel](http://I%20think%20the%20easiest%20way%20is%20to%20use%20NSThread%27s%20-%28void%29cancel%20method.) method.